# How can I dynamically set the site URL (in Drush9+)?

Tags: drush

In Drush 8 I had that neat little reusable line in my `drushrc.php`:

```
$options['l'] = getenv('MY_SITE_URL_VAR');
```

I know that I can hardcode my site URL in a `drush.yml` file, but that does not fit my configuration workflows, where each server knows its URL.

So how can I set the `l` option from an environment variable?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how you can easily reproduce that (nice) configuration setup since the yaml files are indeed static.

The only solution I see is to write a little wrapper script that always calls drush with the `--uri` option, like:

```
drush --uri $MY_SITE_URL_VAR $@
```

### Recommended solution

A much simpler solution is to use the shell variable `DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI`.

```
export DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI=http://example.com
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation for this, but it seems to work.

Comment: Now documented in https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drush.yml